# Compound metal oxide stoichiometries

Tags: experimental-chemistry, solid-state-chemistry

When certain oxides are combined in a pre-determined stoichiometry and synthesized with a ceramic-like synthesis process(power-in-tube), multiple phases may be obtained which not necessarily is same as the original stoichiometry desired. For example, in the superconducting compound $\ce{YBa2Cu3O_{7−x}}$, other ratios such as $\ce{YBa2Cu4O_y}$ (Y124) or $\ce{Y2Ba4Cu7O_y}$ (Y247) might exist in the same material.

From stoichiometry perspective,

1. Is there a limit on the number of oxides due to crystal lattice limitations and such?
2. What precautions can be taken during synthesis of these oxides when partial stoichiometries are involved?

**EDIT:** FCC for example, accommodates a max of 14 atoms per unit cell which YBCO does. But take for example Bi2223. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225413281_Crystal_structure_and_superconductivity_of_Bi-2223
This has a crystal structure, unlike any traditional lattices.
The question I have is to what extent can one go to obtain desired stoichiometry? Bi2234, for instance, is hard to synthesize: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bismuth_strontium_calcium_copper_oxide. How do we know beforehand (educated guess) that a certain phase is not easy to synthesize?

Comment: So I've been thinking about how to answer this question appropriately for a while now. I'm not quite sure how deep into phase diagrams you want to go, however. In short, there is no limit on the number of possible oxide phases. Even 'simple' binary metal phase diagrams can have a dozen or more phases on them. As for precautions, well, that depends a lot on the particulars of the phase diagram and how you are trying to make the phase. How deep do you want to go?

Comment: I'm primarily interested in increasing the size of the unit cell while ensuring the synthesis produces a predominantly single phase so the unit cell satisfies the originally intended stoichiometry. For example, YBCO satisfies the ABC3 lattice. Increasing the number of oxides or their relative ratios under prime factors (3:7:11)  obviously gives fractional unit cell that satisfies some lattice structure but that's not the intent. We want the unit cell to be consistent with desired stoichiometry.

Comment: The question still boils down to how do you think you might guess different phases are not formed?

Comment: So are you looking to (1) add other elements to increase the unit cell size but keep it as 123, or (2) by adding other elements get to an ordered phase that retains the basic 123 structure but has multiple 123-type unit cells in its (larger) unit cell? By your edit it still isn't completely clear. However, I will try to gin up a fairly simple answer that may address some of your points.

Comment: @ViníciusGodim: yes, that's the fundamental problem. Associated with are the questions like, what oxide combinations, how to deal with partial stoichiometries. Also, Jon Custer, it need not be 123, I gave that as an example. To clarify, mentioned Bi2223 which isn't 123. It boils to the same question. What oxides to pick to grow the unit size (with higher stoichiometry) so a single phase forms?